# Connect Power BI to FTP

Tags: r, ftp, powerbi

I have .gz files sitting on FTP. Can we directly connect Power BI to FTP? If yes please tell how should I proceed.
As per my research, we can not directly connect Power BI to FTP so I am trying to connect using R - script present inside power BI but I think R has some data storage limitation (data used by the R visual for plotting is limited to 150,000 rows).

Please let me know any alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use a logic app (or flow) or an azure function to move the files to Azure Blob storage, then load the files into Power BI from there. See the following for a quick start on ftp to blob that may give you some pointers

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-logic-app-ftp-to-blob